# Lock Ubuntu Server 12.0.4

Tags: server, lock

How do I lock Ubuntu server screen without installing gnome screensaver?

I'm running the server with only the console without desktop installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vlock` does the trick.

`apt-get install vlock`.

Comment: Wow! vlock does it in a sec. Thanks a lot for all your input!

Comment: If this is the answer you was looking for, you should mark it as such. That's also a way of saying thank you. ;-)

Comment: You know I was looking for where to do that but can't find it. Just found it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you mean a basic X screen, you could install and run `xlock` to accomplish screen lock. If you mean in a virtual terminal, then you need to just logout, with Ctrl+D, or running the `exit` command. If you need to keep some processes running while logged out, you should look at using `byobu`, `tmux` (which byobu uses for the terminal management), or `screen`.